# Why $\frac{1}{(\frac{\pi}{4})^\beta|\log(x)|^\beta}$ is convergent $\forall \beta$ near $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $x\to 0$, shouldn't $\log(x)\to -\infty$? Then why  $\frac{1}{(\pi/4)^\beta|\log(x)|^\beta}$ is convergent $\forall \beta$ near $x=0$? If $\beta$ is negative, then shouldn't it be divergent?

Also, is $\int\frac{1}{(\pi/4)^\beta|\log(x)|^\beta}$ integrable near $x=0$ $\forall \beta$?

Comment: yup, so you have bad sources :)

Comment: maybe whoever said $\forall \beta$ meant $\forall \beta > 0$

Comment: @mathworker21 If that function is divergent near $x=0$, does that mean that the integral of that function is not integrable in $x=0$ $\forall \beta$?

Comment: no. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is divergent near $x=0$ but is integrable near $x=0$.

Comment: i dont know why I gave that example lol. $\log x$ is integrable near $x=0$

Comment: I see, thank you!